# powershell get PATH variable change log in eventviewer

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, event-log

Am trying to get the event log detailed information for PATH environment variable change from System and Security events but unable to get it easily.

I tried `Get-EventLog system | Format-List` and `Get-EventLog Security | Format-List` but its giving other details. Is there any way to get the details log for PATH environment variable change from when the server provisioned on Windows 2008 R2?

Comment: Is the issue that events are being logged for environment variable changes but you're having trouble querying and displaying them the way you want, or no such events are being logged?  If the latter, see [Audit Logs for Environment Path Changes](http://serverfault.com/q/707929/15583) and [How to tell what is changing a windows environment variable](https://superuser.com/q/896263/34985).

Comment: Having problem in querying and displaying environment variable changes.

Comment: Am seeing logs only for the messages `An attempt was made to access an object` and `A handle to an object was requested` and not seeing any logs like `A registry value for modified`.

Comment: On my system when I change the `%PATH%` environment variable through System Properties I see log entries with the two messages you noted, followed by a log entry for each environment variable with message `Registry value deleted`, followed by a log entry for each environment variable with message `New registry variable created`.  Both sets of log entries use ID `4657` and keyword `Audit Success`.  Do you have auditing enabled on the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` registry key as described in the questions I linked above?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have auditing configured to monitor the registry key that stores environment variables...

1. Set `Local Security Policy` => `Security Settings` => `Local Policies` => `Audit Policy` => `Audit object access` to `Success` or `Success, Failure`.
2. On the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` registry key add an audit rule for the `Everyone` principal and at least the `Set value` permission.

...you can run the following from an elevated PowerShell session to retrieve the event log entries created by modifiying the `%PATH%` environment variable.  The output objects will contain select properties common to all event log entry types as well as those specifically for a registry modification event, so you can access which user and process changed `%PATH%` and to/from what value.

```
$auditingProviderName = 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing';
$registryValueModifiedEventId = 4657;

$auditingProvider = Get-WinEvent -ListProvider $auditingProviderName;
# Get the metadata for the "registry value modified" event
$registryValueModifiedEvent = $auditingProvider.Events `
    | Where-Object -Property 'ID' -EQ -Value $registryValueModifiedEventId;
# Store an array of property names in the order they will appear in each log entry
$registryValueModifiedEventPropertyNames = $registryValueModifiedEvent.Template `
    | Select-Xml `
        -Namespace @{ 'default' = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events'; } `
        -XPath '/default:template/default:data' `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Node' `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'name';

# Construct an XPath expression to filter for auditing events where the Path value of the Environment key has been modified
# This assumes HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet is a link to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001
$xpathFilter = @"
    *[
        System[
            Provider[@Name = '$auditingProviderName']
                and EventID = $registryValueModifiedEventId
        ]
    ]
    [
        EventData[
            Data[@Name = 'ObjectName'] = '\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment'
                and Data[@Name = 'ObjectValueName'] = 'Path'
        ]
    ]
"@;
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Security' -FilterXPath $xpathFilter `
    | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $outputProperties = [Ordered] @{
            MachineName = $_.MachineName;
            TimeCreated = $_.TimeCreated;
            #TODO: Copy additional properties from the event log entry object ($_)
        };

        # Copy each log entry property value to an output object property of the same name
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $registryValueModifiedEventPropertyNames.Length; $i++)
        {
            $name = $registryValueModifiedEventPropertyNames[$i];
            $value = $_.Properties[$i].Value;

            $outputProperties[$name] = $value;
        }

        return New-Object -TypeName 'PSObject' -Property $outputProperties;
    };
```